Using multiple CPUs and multiple cores in python
I am trying to implement parallel processing in python.
CDSW environment has options 1vCPU, 2vCPU,...,4vCPU.
Irrespective of the option selected, it has 16 cores(nproc --all)
I was able to run 4 parallel jobs using multiprocessing package.
Parallel(n_jobs=4, prefer="threads")(delayed(execute_function){....}
more than 4 parallel jobs, is causing memory overload error
I was hoping for a way to make use of all 4vCPUs ., with 4 cores in each => 16 parallel jobs.
Additional Info:
python 3.6
execute_function => pyspark, pandas processing code.

Memory issues aren't related to the number of cores but the memory efficiency of the code itself. If the code creates a full copy of the data instead of partitioning it among workers, you waste any benefit of partitioning and quickly exhaust memory. Besides, vCPU means virtual CPU. Multiple VMs are probably sharing the same physical CPUs and worse, the same RAM.

python 3.6 that's not just old, it's already beyond the End Of Life mark. The current Python version is 3.12. Pandas itself is at version 2.2.2 and requires Python 3.9 at least. Newer versions introduced significant performance and memory management improvements.

In my office, am restricted to use python 3.6 or python 3.7
because of pyspark 2.x compatibility.

The current version of PySpark is 3.5.1 which requires Python 3.8 at least. In fact, I suspect you're using an old version of PySpark because someone didn't want to upgrade 3 years ago, not the other way around. The easiest way to optimize your code is to install the latest versions. Otherwise you'll struggle to reimplement the same optimizations introduced in the last 3 years
